# How to do basic row name mapping of matrix in R?

Tags: r

I have very big matrix called `A`, I need to add one column to that matrix, which is the mapped row names of this matrix from  other matrix called `B` .
row names of matrix A are in column called `ID` and it's mapped name is in column `Sample`

Here iss simple reproduceable example and expected output.

```
A<-cbind(c("a","b", "c"), c(1,2,3), c(10,14,15))
rownames(A)<-c("q","w","r")   

> A
  [,1] [,2] [,3]
q "a"  "1"  "10"
w "b"  "2"  "14"
r "c"  "3"  "15"
```

and second matrix, which row names of matrix A are in column `ID` and it's mapped name is in `Sample` column:

```
B<-cbind(c("d1","f2","g5","y4"),c("q","L","w","r"),c("qw","we","zr","ls"))  

colnames(B)<-c("M","ID","Sample"
> B
     M    ID  Sample
[1,] "d1" "q" "qw"  
[2,] "f2" "L" "we"  
[3,] "g5" "w" "zr"  
[4,] "y4" "r" "ls"  
>
```

Here is the expected output:

```
A<-cbind(c("a","b", "c"), c(1,2,3), c(10,14,15), c("qw","zr","ls"))
rownames(A)<-c("q","w","r")    
> A
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
q "a"  "1"  "10" "qw"
w "b"  "2"  "14" "zr"
r "c"  "3"  "15" "ls"
>
```

Would someone help me to implement it in R ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the merge function in R.

```
> A <-matrix( data = NA, nrow = 3, ncol =3)
> A[1,] <- c("a" , "1",  "10")
> A[2,] <- c( "b" , "2" , "14")
> A[3,] <- c("c" , "3" , "15")
> 
> row.names(A) = c("q","w","r")
> 
> 
> B <- matrix(data = "NA" , nrow = 4, ncol = 3)
> B[1,] <- c("d1" ,"q" ,"qw")
> B[2,] <- c( "f2" ,"L" ,"we")
> B[3,] <- c("g5" ,"w", "zr")
> B[4,] <- c("y4", "r", "ls" )
> colnames(B) = c("M", "ID",  "Sample")
> A
  [,1] [,2] [,3]
q "a"  "1"  "10"
w "b"  "2"  "14"
r "c"  "3"  "15"
> B
     M    ID  Sample
[1,] "d1" "q" "qw"  
[2,] "f2" "L" "we"  
[3,] "g5" "w" "zr"  
[4,] "y4" "r" "ls"  
> 
> C <- merge(A, B, by.x = 0, by.y = "ID" )
> D <- C[,-5]
> D
  Row.names V1 V2 V3 Sample
1         q  a  1 10     qw
2         r  c  3 15     ls
3         w  b  2 14     zr
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there just putting the sample matrices together.

While we cannot use the `$` operator on matrices, we can use the `dimnames` (as well as the row/column numbers) to subset the matrix. Then we can find which `ID` are in the row names of `A` with `%in%`

```
> cbind(A, B[,"Sample"][B[,"ID"] %in% rownames(A)])
#   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# q "a"  "1"  "10" "qw"
# w "b"  "2"  "14" "zr"
# r "c"  "3"  "15" "ls"
```

Comment: Could it be necessary to first sort `B` in case the entries in `B[,"ID"]` don't appear in the same order as in `rownames(A)`? (Although it is not really clear from the question, what the expected outcome is in such a case)

Comment: Good point.  `order` doesn't work the same on matrices and is a bit tricky.  If you want to submit an answer based on this one, I'll delete this one.